# Find best possible paths based on answered questions (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I'm currently doing is finding all possible paths for answers based on questions answered. However what I'm struggling with is that it's just comparing array items to find possible paths instead of matching the order as well.

Does anyone have any ideas how this can be resolved?

**What I have so far:**

```js
const originalQuestions = {
    1: {
        title: "Title",
        firstQuestion: true,
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 2
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 2
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 10000
        }]
    },
    2: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 3
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 3
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 3
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 3
        }]
    },
    3: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 4
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 4
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 4
        }]
    },
    4: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 13
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 5
        }]
    },
    5: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 6
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 6
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 6
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 10000
        }]
    },
    6: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 7
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 7
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 7
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 7
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 14
        }]
    },
    7: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 17
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 17
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 17
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 17
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 17
        }]
    },
    8: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 9
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 9
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 9
        }]
    },
    9: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 10
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 10
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 10
        }]
    },
    10: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 11
        }, {
            value: "Roof",
            attribute: "Flue Exit",
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 15
        }]
    },
    11: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 12
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 12
        }]
    },
    12: {
        finalQuestion: true,
        input: true,
        placeHolder: 'e.g SWS'
    },
    13: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 6
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 6
        }]
    },
    14: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 7
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 7
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 10000
        }]
    },
    15: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 12
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 12
        }]
    },
    17: {
        title: "Title",
        options: [{
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 8
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 8
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 8
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 8
        }, {
            tooltip: "",
            nextQuestion: 8
        }]
    },
    // Errors
    10000: {
        isError: true,
        title: "Finally, what is the first part of your postcode?",
        error: "Postcode"
    }
};

class QuestionAnswerPossibilities {
    constructor(questions, ...path) {
        // Data fields
        this.questions = questions;
        this.path = path;

        // Derived fields
        const currentStep = this.path[this.path.length-1];
        this.currentQuetion = this.questions[currentStep];
        this.isFinished = this.currentQuetion.finalQuestion || this.currentQuetion.isError || false;
    }

    clone(andNextStep) {
        return new QuestionAnswerPossibilities(this.questions, ...this.path, andNextStep);
    }

    possibleNext() {
        const nextSteps = (this.currentQuetion.options ? this.currentQuetion.options : []).map(x => x.nextQuestion);

        return new Set(nextSteps);
    }

    takeStep() {
        if (this.isFinished)
            return [this];

        return Array.from(this.possibleNext(), step => this.clone(step));
    }

    static start(questions) {
        //find any possible first questions
        const first = Object.entries(questions)
            .filter(([key, q]) => q.firstQuestion);

        //for each first question create an agent
        let pathExplorers = first.map(([start]) => new QuestionAnswerPossibilities(questions, start));

        //get all agents to continue until they are all finished
        while (pathExplorers.some(x => !x.isFinished))
            pathExplorers = pathExplorers.flatMap(x => x.takeStep());

        return pathExplorers;
    }
}

let result = QuestionAnswerPossibilities.start(originalQuestions).map(agent => agent.path);
result = result.map(path => path.map(step => String(step)));

let questionsAnswered = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "13", "6", "7", "17", "8", "9", "10", "11"];
let possibleResults = [];

const MatchingAnswerPaths = (answerPaths, questionsAnswered) => {
    let possiblePaths = [];

    answerPaths.forEach(answerPath => {
        let matchingPathFound = questionsAnswered.every(r => answerPath.includes(r));

        if (matchingPathFound) {
            possiblePaths.push(answerPath);
        }
    });

    return possiblePaths;
}

console.log(MatchingAnswerPaths(result, questionsAnswered));
```

**The part i'm struggling with:**

What is the best way of checking the order but also check if answered questions are contained in the possibility path. There will be few numbers not filled in yet as the answered aren't complete.

```
const MatchingAnswerPaths = (answerPaths, questionsAnswered) => {
    let possiblePaths = [];

    answerPaths.forEach(answerPath => {
        let matchingPathFound = questionsAnswered.every(r => answerPath.includes(r));

        if (matchingPathFound) {
            possiblePaths.push(answerPath);
        }
    });

    return possiblePaths;
}
```

**What is currently being returned from the above possiblePaths:**

```
[
  [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "13",
    "6",
    "7",
    "17",
    "8",
    "9",
    "10",
    "11",
    "12"
  ],
  [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "13",
    "6",
    "14",
    "7",
    "17",
    "8",
    "9",
    "10",
    "11",
    "12"
  ]
]
```

**What has been answered by user:**

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "13", "6", "7", "17", "8", "9", "10", "11"]
```

**What should being returned based on the provided answered questions:**

```
[
  ["1", "2", "3", "4", "13", "6", "7", "17", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"]
]
```

Comment: It isn't: `6,7,17` vs `6,14,7,17`

Comment: I have a suggestion for you before you ask this question. You should minimise your question and show what are you struggling.

Comment: So do you want to find all possible paths along the questions until you reach the last question?

Comment: I am still not sure what do you want to achieve in the question.

Comment: @YaBCK give me some time

Comment: @ikhvjs - I've just updated further, hope this finally gives you the information what you're after

Comment: @YaBCK, I understand now. I will wait for AlphaHowl to answer first. If it is still not yet solved, I will come back.

Comment: @ikhvjs I've managed to resolve it. If you guys think there is an easier and neater way I'm open to suggests below.

Comment: @YaBCK, good to hear!

Comment: @YaBCK I'm glad! I managed to misread the question, and thought your code was doing something else... So I came up with a completely different solution. Whoops xd

Answer (score 1):

After spending some time away from my desk and having a cup of tea. I have managed to come back and resolve what I'm looking for.

What the issue was that the original code was only checking if item values are in the possibility paths. Now it's check for the order of answers and comparing it to order of possibility paths.

**Original code:**

```
const MatchingAnswerPaths = (answerPaths, questionsAnswered) => {
    let possiblePaths = [];

    answerPaths.forEach(answerPath => {
        let matchingPathFound = questionsAnswered.every(r => answerPath.includes(r));

        if (matchingPathFound) {
            possiblePaths.push(answerPath);
        }
    });

    return possiblePaths;
}
```

**Answer Code:**

```
const MatchingAnswerPaths = (answerPaths, questionsAnswered) => {
    let possiblePaths = [];

    answerPaths.forEach(answerPath => {
        let matchingPathFound = questionsAnswered.every((r, index) => {          
            return answerPath[index] === r;
        });

        if (matchingPathFound) {
            possiblePaths.push(answerPath);
        }
    });

    return possiblePaths;
}
```